# Pandas/Python Adding row or modify row based on some conditon

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've a DataFrame that contains agent shift deatils, i want to adjust their Break if they are not following the certain rules , if they are following then no need to do anything.

Rule 1:
**The agent can Take break after 1h from shift start and need to take within 3h from shift start.**
**The Break Duration is 15min**
I have these are the columns  First Name, Last Name, Shift Date, Shift Start,
Shift End, Scheduled Activity, Exception Start, Exception End
Scheduled Activity columns holds the information what the agent is doing for example
Open- Agent is Working
Lunch -Agent is on Lunch
Break-First occurance of Break need to be taken based on Rule 1.
Break - second Occurance of Break
**Other than Open,Break,Lunch we can not modify anything.**

InPut Data(Case 1)

| First Name | Last Name | Shift Date | Shift Start | Shift End | Scheduled Activity | Exception Start | Exception End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Open | 07:00 | 11:00 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Lunch | 11:00 | 12:00 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Open | 12:00 | 14:15 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Break | 14:15 | 14:30 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Open | 14:30 | 16:00 |

Output Data (Case 2):

| First Name | Last Name | Shift Date | Shift Start | Shift End | Scheduled Activity | Exception Start | Exception End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Open | 07:00 | 08:00 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Break | 08:00 | 08:15 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Open | 08:15 | 11:00 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Lunch | 11:00 | 12:00 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Open | 12:00 | 14:15 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Break | 14:15 | 14:30 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Open | 14:30 | 16:00 |

We can allocate break inbetween 08:00 to 11:00

Input Data(case 2)

| First Name | Last Name | Shift Date | Shift Start | Shift End | Scheduled Activity | Exception Start | Exception End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | RTO | 07:00 | 11:00 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Lunch | 11:00 | 12:00 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Open | 12:00 | 14:15 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Break | 14:15 | 14:30 |
| Johnson | Cynthia | 22-11-2023 | 07:00 | 16:00 | Open | 14:30 | 16:00 |

For Case 2 The output will be same as input as we can't change anything other than 'Open','Break','Lunch', In this Case RTO is scheduled form 07:00 to 11:00 , if it wa scheduled from 07:00 to 09:00 in this case we can allocate Break inbetween 09:00 to 10:00

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

data = {
    'First Name': ['Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Johnson'],
    'Last Name': ['Cynthia', 'Cynthia', 'Cynthia', 'Cynthia', 'Cynthia'],
    'Shift Date': ['22-11-2023', '22-11-2023', '22-11-2023', '22-11-2023', '22-11-2023'],
    'Shift Start': ['07:00', '07:00', '07:00', '07:00', '07:00'],
    'Shift End': ['16:00', '16:00', '16:00', '16:00', '16:00'],
    'Scheduled Activity': ['Open', 'Lunch', 'Open', 'Break', 'Open'],
    'Exception Start': ['07:00', '11:00', '12:00', '14:15', '14:30'],
    'Exception End': ['11:00', '12:00', '14:15', '14:30', '16:00'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Shift Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Shift Date'] + ' ' + df['Shift Start'])
df['Shift End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Shift Date'] + ' ' + df['Shift End'])
df['Exception Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Shift Date'] + ' ' + df['Exception Start'])
df['Exception End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Shift Date'] + ' ' + df['Exception End'])

rows_to_insert = []

for index, record in df.iterrows():
    shift_start_time = record['Shift Start']
    scheduled_activity = record['Scheduled Activity']
    if scheduled_activity == 'Break':
        if not (shift_start_time + timedelta(hours=1) <= record['Exception Start'] <= shift_start_time + timedelta(hours=3)):
            
            available_start_time =shift_start_time + timedelta(hours=1)
            available_end_time = available_start_time + timedelta(hours=2)
            break_time = record['Exception Start']
            
            df.at[index, 'Exception Start'] = available_start_time
            df.at[index, 'Exception End'] = available_end_time
            rows_to_insert.append({
                
                'First Name': record['First Name'],
                'Last Name': record['Last Name'],
                'Shift Date': record['Shift Date'],
                'Shift Start': record['Shift Start'],
                'Shift End': record['Shift End'],
                'Scheduled Activity': 'Open',
                'Exception Start': available_end_time,
                'Exception End': record['Exception End'],
            })

   
df = df.sort_values(by='Exception Start')
```